# Create cronjob in kloxo to run .php file every x minutes

Tags: php, apache, cron, kloxo

I am trying to add a cronjob in the kloxo based user interface,

So i navigate into cron scheduled tasks -> add standard -> Select x minutes, select 'all' in all other fields (hour, day, week, month, ..), then add the path in the last field: `/home/piscolab/public_html/keepyourlinks.com/includes/boot.php`

But the file is never executed,

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. find the problem: check the cron log. if you dont know where your cron log is going to check the syslog. if you cant find anything there kill the cron proccess and start a new one with the **-L /yourlogpath/** parameter specified. wait till the job is supposed to run and check the log after.
2. fix your problem or come back here to get help
3. as i see you dont specify what program should run the *.php file. change that to whatever program you want to run the php file.
4. if you use linux and the gui/webgui sux, fall back to shell. cron jobs are defined within /etc/spool/crond/crontab/root (or something similar to that, cant remember the exact path right now, but using TABSTOP will do the job for you). the crontab syntax can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205). [Cron newbies go here as well.](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: i see.. well i followed same method that i was doing in cpanel... thanks will be back ;)